# How to set a unique id for an embedded document in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I have setup my collections like this using Simple Schema :

```
SubLinkSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Link Name',
        unique: false
    },
    link: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Url,
        label: 'Custom Link',
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            class: 'sub-custom-link'
        }
    }

});

LinkSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Link Name',
        unique: false
    },
    link: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Url,
        label: 'Custom Link',
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            class: 'main-custom-link'
        }
    },
    subLinks: {
        optional: true,
        label: 'Sub Links',
        unique: false,
        type: [SubLinkSchema]
    }
});
```

In here, the problem is, the sublinks do not get an ID. Its hard to update them without an id. So, how can I generate a unique ID per sublink (embedded document)?

Comment: Look up `Random.Id()`.

Comment: @Kyll Will it be unique?

Comment: Im agree with MrE, should use "autoValue" from SimpleSchema, but take a look at this package:  https://atmospherejs.com/mantarayar/shortid 
Its very easy to use, and the ids looks like mongo ids.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use an autovalue field in the SimpleSchema

see ref here: 
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#autovalue

and example:

```
subLinkID: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
        return Meteor.uuid();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Meteor.uuid() has been depricated.  It's recommended to use Random.id() instead.

Answer (score 0):

It should go with the

`Meteor.uuid()`